# Insertar y restar datos en tablas distintas usando php sql

Tags: php, sql

Tengo una tabla llamada ticket

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ticket` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_usuario` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tipo_solicitud` set('1','2','3','4') NOT NULL,
  `prioridad` set('300','400','500','600','700','800','900','1000','1500','2000','2500','3000','3500','4000','4500','5000','5500','6000','6500','7000','7500','8000','8500','9000','9500','10000','10500','11000','11500','12000') NOT NULL,
  `titulo` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `observacion` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;
```

y una table usuario

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `usuario` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_persona` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_departamento` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(31) NOT NULL,
  `clave` char(32) NOT NULL,
  `tipo` set('1','2','3','4','5') NOT NULL,
  `cartera` int(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_persona` (`id_persona`),
  UNIQUE KEY `nombre` (`nombre`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

estoy ingresando ticket a mi sistema y lo hago bien ya en un formulario que llama a una funcion

```
   <?php function addTicket($conexion){

            mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO ticket (id_usuario, tipo_solicitud, prioridad, titulo, observacion, status, fecha_creacion, hora_creacion)
                                     VALUES ('".$this->idUsuario."', '".$this->tipoSolicitud."', '".$this->prioridad."', '".$this->titulo."',
                                             '".$this->observacion."', '".$this->status."', '".$this->fecha."', '".$this->hora."')")
                                     or die("Error insertando nuevo Ticket: ".mysqli_error($conexion));
        } 

?>
```

Lo que intento hacer es restar el valor de la cartera cada vez que se haga un insert.

Intente agregando otra conexion a la funcion y hacer el update en la misma funcion asi pero no me resta

```
mysqli_query($conexion,"UPDATE usuario SET cartera='cartera - ".$this->prioridad."' WHERE id=".mysqli_insert_id($conexion)." ");
```

Comment: Por que no lo haces en dos sentencias diferentes?

Answer (score 0):

la solucion fue crear otra funcion para llamarla dentro del insert (justo despues)pasandole los parametros que necesitaba

```
/* funcion agregada */
function editCartera($conexion, $id, $valor){
        mysqli_query($conexion, "UPDATE usuario SET cartera=cartera-".$valor." WHERE id=".$id." ") or die("Error editando Persona: ".mysqli_error($conexion));
    }

/* momento del insert */
$ticket->addTicket($conexion); //momento cuando hago el insert
$usuario->editCartera($conexion, $_SESSION['ticket_id'], $_POST['prioridad']);
```

espero que a alguien mas le ayude el ejemplo